# How to pass `_metadata` to `Sentry.init` to remove sentry_client number from the request url?

Tags: javascript, sentry

How to pass `_metadata` to `Sentry.init` to remove sentry_client number from the request url?

```
Sentry.init({
 dns: sentry_dns,
 _metadata: ?
})
```

I'm not sure whether `sdkInfo` variable in `getEnvelopeEndpointWithUrlEncodedAuth` in `@sentry/core/esm/api.js` always return `tunnelOrOptions._metadata.sdk`